# Set interword spacing locally under xelatex

Tags: spacing, xetex, fontspec

How can I reduce interword spacing in XeLaTeX for a single object (for example, I want to shrink space between words only in captions)? I know that, using `fontspec` the option to set interword spacing for the font in general is `WordSpace`, but I see that this cannot be set locally in `\addfontfeature{WordSpace=0.8}`. On the other hand, the LaTeX command `\fontdimen2` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `\setlength\spaceskip{1pt}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the main font twice, one with the `WordSpace` option. Then you can use `caption` to ease defining how the caption is formatted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily{\tightfont}{Libertinus Serif}[
  WordSpace=0.3 % exaggerated
]

\DeclareCaptionFormat{tight}{#1#2\tightfont#3\par}
\captionsetup{format=tight}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Figure 1. This is text with some word spacing.
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{This is text with some word spacing.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, set `\spaceskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newcommand{\tightfont}{%
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{
    0.3\fontdimen2\font
    plus 0.3\fontdimen2\font
    minus 0.3\fontdimen3\font
  }%
}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{tight}{#1#2\tightfont#3\par}
\captionsetup{format=tight}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Figure 1. This is text with some word spacing.
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{This is text with some word spacing.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```